# Getting 'Segmentation fault' while reading a tab delimited file in c

Tags: c

I am trying to read the following tab-delimited file in a structure, but getting the `segmentation fault`. My code is unable to read the values.

----exdata.txt----

```
ID  seq len
082054  AAAG    4
53948   AAAGGGATAGAAAAAACGAA    37
53948   AAAGGGAGACTTTGGATAAGG   39
253 ALFPGELDY   15
085241  ASHHHHHH    23
184152  ASAS    11
184152  AGGSGASAS   16
184152  AGGGSGASAS  21
184152  AGGGSGASAS  26
184152  AASGASAS    31
184152  AAAGSGXSGASAS   13
```

Code :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>


int main()
{
    char field1[32], field2[32], field3[32];
    char *p;
    int bufferSize =100;
    FILE* infile_ptr = fopen("exdata.txt", "r");
    char line[bufferSize];

    while(fgets(line, bufferSize, infile_ptr) != NULL)
    {
        printf("%s", line);
        p = strtok(line, '\t');
        int itr = 0;
        while(p != NULL) {
            if(itr == 0){
                strcpy(field1, p);
                itr++;
            }
            else if(itr == 1){
                strcpy(field2, p);
                itr++;
            }
            else {
                strcpy(field3, p);
                itr = 0;
            }
            p = strtok(NULL, '\t');
        }
        printf("This is what read: %s%s%s", field1, field2, field3);
        fclose(infile_ptr);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Error:

```
$ gcc try2.c
try2.c: In function ‘main’:
try2.c:17: warning: passing argument 2 of ‘strtok’ makes pointer from integer without a cast
try2.c:32: warning: passing argument 2 of ‘strtok’ makes pointer from integer without a cast

$ ./a.out
ID  seq len
Segmentation fault: 11
```

Comment: Your `myData` is an indeterminate pointer and thus your code invokes **undefined behavior**.

Comment: You use `strtok` multiple times on your input string. `strtok` returns *pointers* to data, and you overwrite `line` in the next call to `fgets`. Now even if `myData` pointed to something useful (as noted in the answer), if you change the `line` these results won't be anything useful anymore.

Comment: @Jongware, You were right. I solved the above problem, except this one. How can I get first two elements from `111\txxxxxxxx\t66\n`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You never allocate (or set) `myData` - it could be pointing anywhere!

At a glance it looks like what you want to do is create some kind of list list of `kvstructures` (one per line). You need to `malloc` a `kvstructure` for each record.

```
myData = malloc(sizeof(kvstructure));
```

Then after you have populated it you need to add it to a list. A simple approach would be to add a `kvstructure *next` member to the `kvstructure` and the the list is just a `kvstructure*`